# Issues with packages recognizing external header files

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am currently trying to get a given catkin package(description) to recognize header files stored in another catkin package(cat_ball). However, when I attempt to run catkin_make I get this error

```
fatal error: simulation/ControllerSimulator.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

(Note: simulation/ControllerSimulator.h does exist in cat_ball/include)

Below is the CMakeLists.txt file and yes I have made sure that description is both run_dependent and build_dependent on cat_ball in the package.xml and that cat_ball is also a catkin package.

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(description)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp gazebo_ros cat_ball)

# Find gazebo
include (FindPkgConfig)
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
  pkg_check_modules(GAZEBO gazebo)
endif()

link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/plugin.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

catkin_package(DEPENDS roscpp gazebo_ros CATKIN_DEPENDS cat_ball)
```

If anyone could help me with this problem I would be very grateful, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66917/issues-with-packages-recognizing-external-header-files/) by [mwd](https://answers.ros.org/users/5357/mwd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-09**:
Please post additional information. Especially the `CMakeLists.txt` of the "cat_ball" package. I guess you have both packages in a single workspace and invoked `catkin_make` for it?

**Comment by [mwd](https://answers.ros.org/users/5357/mwd/) on 2013-07-09**:
Sorry about that, I'll remember it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

find_package() should add all the INCLUDE_DIRS from the specified packages into the INCLUDE_DIRS of the current package.  So I'd suspect that cat_ball isn't properly exporting its include folder. You should check the cat_ball/CMakeLists.txt and make sure it has a line like this:

```
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include)
```

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mwd](https://answers.ros.org/users/5357/mwd/) on 2013-07-09**:
That was the correct fix, thanks.